# Как сделать переменные lat и lon глобальными, чтобы они были видимыми за пределами функции?

Tags: javascript, переменные, return

```js
//Получение координат пользователя сайта
function coordinateUser() {
    var writeCoord = document.getElementById('coord');
    var msg = 'Координаты отсутствуют.';
    console.log(navigator.geolocation);

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        writeCoord.textContent = 'Определение местоположения..';
    } else {
        writeCoord.textContent = msg;
    }

    function success(position) {
        var lat = (position.coords.latitude).toFixed(8);
        var lon = (position.coords.longitude).toFixed(8);
        var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
        msg = `${lat}, ${lon} <br>погрешность(в метрах): ${accuracy}`;
        writeCoord.innerHTML = msg;
    }
    function error(msg) {
        writeCoord.textContent = msg;
        console.log(msg.code);
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделать можно, но вам это все равно не поможет :) Вам надо научиться работать с асинхронным кодом.

Comment: Правда не поможет? Мне просто нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, были получены долгота и широта пользователя, и чтобы эти координаты были переданы для создания маркера на карте по этим данным

Comment: Может помочь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/

Comment: Правда правда не поможет. Приведите пример кода для создания маркера - попробуем вам помочь их соединить.